# Android URI wrong path why?

Tags: java, android, file, path, uri

I have a file

```
File tempFile = ....// creating the file
String fPath = temFile.getPath(); //this will return - /storage/emulated/0/Pictures/A
//After that I get the URI
URI uuu = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this,
                        "com.example....app.provider",
                        tempFile);
String uPath = uuu.getPath(); // this will return - /external_files/Pictures/A
```

How can I get the first path from the URI (/storage...). I can't do anything with the second (/external...). Every function I use with the second path results in an error.

At present what I do is I create the file get the URI and also get the path and remember both so later I use whichever I need. Is it not possible to keep just the URI and get the proper path when we need it?

Or perhaps I should have kept just the path and create URI whenever I need it.

I already explained above

Comment: `String uPath = uuu.getPath(); // this will return - /external_files/Pictures/A` That is no path. That is a nonsense path. Have a look at uuu.toString() to see the content scheme for your path.

Comment: Only just remember your files path for later use. You only need an uri fo access if you want to let another app read or write your file.

Comment: If you compare uuu.toString() and uuu.getPath() and had a look at your FileProvider paths xml file you would see where this /external_files/ came from. And yes at the moment you understand how getUriForFile() works you could decode your file path from the file provider uri.

Comment: `Is it not possible to keep just the URI and get the proper path when we need it?` You could just keep the uri and use the uri when you need it.There is no reason to get path back from uri as you can use the uri to read and write your file and even to delete it.

Answer (score 0):

The difference between the two paths you are seeing is because one is a file system path: /storage/emulated/0/Pictures/A and the other is a content URI path /external_files/Pictures/A that is provided by android FileProvider.

You can't get the real file path from a URI returned by a FileProvider directly. The URI is content://scheme and it's not a file://scheme. The FileProvider is providing an abstraction to the actual file location. If you need the real file path, you should store it when you create the file.

If you are sure that you will only be using the file in your own app, you might opt for keeping the file path and creating a URI when needed to share it. You can create the URI using FileProvider.getUriForFile() whenever you need it.

From my experience, I use FileProvider only when I had to provide access to local files to other apps. Internally I used known location of such files - using their absolute paths.